# DHCP Problems Virtualbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, udev, dhcp

I have some minor issues with Ubuntu server on a virtual machine and even though I have some assumptions as to what actually happens, I'd like to ask all of you about your opinion.

**Here's the deal:** I have a new laptop from my new workplace and there is a Ubuntu Virtualbox VM on it. The network configuration of the VM is a bridged network and `network-manager` is being uninstalled. DHCP is running as it is by default and a static IP will not be set in the future.

When I get the laptop home it isn't able to obtain an IP from my network if left with the mentioned settings. I'd tried only one solution for now due to the limited time I had then, but I was thinking about the very reason for this behavior - why can't this VM box get an IP when the laptop is moved between locations?

Answer (score 0):

If the VM is configured as a bridged device, and it doesn't make use of DHCP to get an IP on whatever network it's attached to, then it won't be able to access the network and/or internet.

I would confirm that the intent is that the VM should be using a bridged network device given all this, since it sounds more like they intended for the guest VM to make use of a NAT networked device, rather than bridged, especially without NetworkManager being available.